# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip

I tried:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Here's the error I received:

```
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
 C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6c3rea1s\pycocotools\
 You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
 You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'
 command.
```

So, I tried:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and

```
install pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

That resulted in more errors:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:      command:
 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe'
 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-epmkeh4g\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-epmkeh4g\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
 '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
 '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
 egg_info --egg-base
 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-epmkeh4g\pycocotools\pip-egg-info'
         cwd:
 C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-epmkeh4g\pycocotools\
    Complete output (5 lines):  Traceback (most recent call last):   
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>     File
 "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-epmkeh4g\pycocotools\setup.py",
 line 2, in <module>        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out
 with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full
 command output.
```

I deleted the folder and re-install, but the results remained the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in [pycocotools](https://pypi.org/project/pycocotools/). The bug was fixed [in 2017](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/commit/2f074ecd262878ecae04897473c1c76df341efa6#diff-67ce1b5ac0d08545f41c97b6ae12c928) but it seems the fix didn't get into release 2.0 in 2018 (I guess the release process is also buggy).

There is also another similar bug in [`setup.py`](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/8c9bcc3cf640524c4c20a9c40e89cb6a2f2fa0e9/PythonAPI/setup.py#L2) — it imports `numpy` before installing it.

There is no simple workarounds for these bugs using `requirements.txt`. You need to install the required modules before installing `pycocotools`:

```
pip install Cython numpy
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I had a similar issue when installing pandas on MacOS. The trick I used to install numpy with the installation was:

`python3 -m pip install pandas`